# NoSQL и SQL базы данных в одном проекте

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Всем привет. Вопрос про приложение, написанное на Java с использование Spring Boot 2. Возможно ли на лету менять бд с sql на nosql и обратно? И как задавать CrudRepository, чтобы по умолчанию он создавал репозиторий для sql базы, а не для nosql, если в зависимостях тянется mongobd и mysql (как пример)?

**UPD:**
У меня висит два подключения. К mysql и mongodb. Немного не описал проблему. У меня есть сущности, который я хочу использовать как в JpaRepository, так и в MongoRepository. В документации выше написано, что смешивать аннотации jpa и mongo (Entity/Document и т.д.) - плохая практика. Так как тогда сделать так, чтобы я мог работать с теми же моделями, но с разных баз данных? Создавать отдельные слои моделей и репозиториев для nosql и sql баз? При работе одновременно я имею ввиду возможность переключаться с одной бд на другую, а не одновременно шарить две базы.

Comment: Что мешает держать 2 подключения сразу?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.multiple-modules

Comment: У меня висит два подключения. К mysql и mongodb. Немного не описал проблему. У меня есть сущности, который я хочу использовать как в JpaRepository, так и в MongoRepository. В документации выше написано, что смешивать аннотации jpa и mongo (Entity/Document и т.д.) - плохая практика. Так как тогда сделать так, чтобы я мог работать с теми же моделями, но с разных баз данных? Создавать отдельные слои моделей и репозиториев для nosql и sql баз? При работе одновременно я имею ввиду возможность переключаться с одной бд на другую, а не одновременно шарить две базы.

Comment: @Michael добавьте лучше это уточнение в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Создавать отдельные слои моделей и репозиториев для nosql и sql баз?

Это будет самый адекватный вариант.

1. Проще поддерживать и расширять
2. Наверняка не просто так используется 2 разные СУБД, задумайтесь, должны-ли модели данных быть идентичными

> Вопрос про приложение, написанное на Java с использование Spring Boot 2. Возможно ли на лету менять бд с sql на nosql и обратно?
>
> При работе одновременно я имею ввиду возможность переключаться с одной бд на другую, а не одновременно шарить две базы.

Можно создавать контекст с необходимым бином репозитория в зависимости от активного профиля и менять профиль пересобирая контекст в рантайме.

Comment: Спасибо. Использую две БД только в учебных целях. Про профили знаю, но прибегать к ним не хочу. Собственно, сделал модели и репозитории для монги отдельно.